# How to stop zeppelin in windows?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I didn't find out how to stop zeppelin in windows 10 !?
it starts with this cmd :

```
bin\zeppelin.cmd
```

is there a cmd to stop it in windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop Zeppelin on Windows need stop `cmd`-process. There isn't `zeppelin-daemon.cmd` in 
https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/tree/master/bin

`Stop` is available only in `zeppelin-daemon.sh` for the Unix systems.